# O que é fazer bind?

Tags: java

Não consigo achar o significado de Bind, que me explique o que é isso.
Gostaria de um exemplo de Bind com a linguagem java, mesmo.

Comment: Onde você viu isso? Tá muito genérico pra responder sem saber de onde você tirou o bind do java.

Comment: Aliás existe bind no java? Meu professor citou esse negócio de bind com dotnet e asp.net. O problema é que eu não sei fazer uma pergunta bacana, mas os programadores já falam em bind.

Comment: http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/asp/asp-net-model-binding-com-web-forms-retornando-e-exibindo-dados-parte-01/

Comment: Se ajuda a melhorar sua pergunta, parece que você quer saber o equivalente ao binding do c# no java.

Comment: Caraca os caras querem fechar a minha pergunta...Nem me ajudaram. Essa comunidade deixa a desejar.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, tente deixar o problema mais claro, veja meu comentario anterior, aparentemente você quer saber algo equivalente ao model binding do c# no java. E tenha paciencia, uma pergunta sendo fechada ou votada pra isso não significa que ela está "perdida". só tente deixar sua dúvida mais clara que ela não será fechada.

Comment: É isso mesmo que queria saber...mas deixa para lá. Esquece pode fechar, perdi o gosto..Eu querendo aprender...deixa para lá.

Comment: Que tal editar a pergunta, deixando isso claro? Nós não sabemos sua dúvida se você não explicá-la. A galera se esforça em ajudar, mas não dá pra advinhar. Edite a pergunta com as dicas que dei, cole o link nela, dessa forma, ficará bem explicito sua duvida.

Comment: @gonz se fizeres uma pergunta que não dá para compreender é teu dever melhorá-la. Nós queremos ajudar, mas sem perceber a pergunta não podemos. Comentários como _"Esquece pode fechar, perdi o gosto"_ dizem-me que achas que estamos contra a pergunta. Pelo contrário, estamos curiosos de saber o que queres, __e até lá__ fechamos pois são as regras do site. Podes [edit] a pergunta para clarificar que eu depois ajudo a limpar aqui os comments. Faz um ping `@Sergio` quando tiveres feito o edit.

Comment: É isso eu não sei como melhorá-la, também por que é algo novo para mim o termo bind. Estive assistindo o hangout do João Batista Neto e os caras já falaram em bind, "bindada". Queria aprender o que é isso. Eu não sei como melhorar a pergunta...

Comment: Queria puder fazer uma pergunta mais clara, mas não consigo. Eu tentei. Vou ler esse artigo: http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/asp/asp-net-model-binding-com-web-forms-retornando-e-exibindo-dados-parte-01/

Comment: @gonz A suspensão da pergunta não quer dizermos que não queremos ajudar ou nada do tipo. Acontece que nós não temos bola de cristal e não tinha como ajudar sem dar um chute passando longe, como pode ser visto nas respostas que temos aqui. Pense do outro lado, como é chato quem respondeu de forma errada o que você tinha perguntado. O cara tem o trabalho de pesquisar, escrever e depois você diz "mas não era isso que eu queria saber". É por esse motivo que precisamos que a pergunta seja clara. Uma dica para evitar que isso aconteça é incluir todos os detalhes possíveis na pergunta. Abraço.

Comment: Certo @utluiz. Agora entendo eu só estava pensando no meu lado. Não imaginei dessa forma que você disse. Foi mal, estou tentando melhorar a cada dia que passa. rs :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Bind* ou *binding* são termos usados em diferentes aplicações, porém em geral fazem referência em como o Java ou qualquer linguagem faz a ligação entre determinadas coisas.

## *Data binding*

Define como dados em diferentes formatos são mapeados de e para objetos. Existem inúmeras possibilidades, onde as mais comuns são:

### *Binding* de requisição HTTP

Consiste em mapear atributos em requisições HTTP para objetos ou mapas. A forma como isso é feito depende do framework.

JSF [por exemplo](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_inputText.html) usa tags especiais como `<h:inputText/>`:

```
<h:inputText value="#{userController.username}" />
```

O exemplo acima iria mapear o campo no HTML com um atributo `String username` na classe `UserController`.

Frameworks como Spring MVC ou compatíveis com JAX-RS geralmente mapeiam cada parâmetro da requisição diretamente para um atributo. Por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" />
```

Seria ligado da seguinte forma:

```
class Usuario { 
    String nome;
    public void setNome(String nome) { ... }
}

class UsuarioController {
    @GET
    @Path("/usuario/incluir)
    public String incluir(Usuario usuario) { ... } 
}
```

### *Binding* de JSON e XML

Dados representados em JSON e XML podem também ser ligados com objetos usando bibliotecas como [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (JSON) e [JAXB](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) (XML).

Exemplo com Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{'nome' : 'Maria'}";
Pessoa pessoa = mapper.readValue(json, Pessoa.class);
```

### *Binding* de bancos de dados

Os exemplos mais conhecidos são frameworks JPA como Hibernate e Eclipselink, onde você pode configurar uma classe de forma que os dados dos campos de uma tabela sejam ligados aos atributos de uma classe, sendo possível enviar e recuperar dados sem escrever cláusulas SQL ou recuperar campo a campo.

Exemplo do mapeamento de uma entidade JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa {
    @Id
    long id;
    String nome;
    String endereco;
    ...
}
```

## *Method binding*

Outro exemplo é o *method binding* ou **ligação de métodos**, que significa como a linguagem faz para determinar qual é o método correto que deverá ser chamado de acordo com diversos fatores:

- Hierarquia de classes, por exemplo quando uma subclasse sobrescreve um método ou quando uma classe implementa o método de uma interface.
- Sobrecarga de métodos, por exemplo quando métodos de mesmo nome recebem parâmetros de diferentes tipos um possuem um número diferente de parâmetros

Em alguns casos é possível determinar o método correto na hora da compilação, por exemplo, se ele for estático ou `final`. Nos demais vasos o método correto é determinado em tempo de execução, o que em teoria é mais lento já que inclui processamento a mais durante a execução do programa. Na verdade, a JVM inclui uma séria de otimizações que tornam o impacto do desempenho praticamente desprezível na maioria dos casos.

## Outros

Outros exemplos de *binding* incluem:

- Como frameworks web MVC decidem qual método chamar de acordo com os parâmetros da requisição e configurações.
- Como frameworks de Injeção de Dependências decidem qual classe injetar baseado em critérios como hierarquia de classes, anotações e configurações.

Answer (score 3):

**Existe o Bind dinâmico e o Bind estático.**

No bind estático, você tem métodos dentro de sua classe principal e os chama direto no `main` (os métodos tem que ser estáticos), ex:

```
public class Main{
    public static void varType(float var){
        System.out.println("Is an float!");
    }

    public static void varType(int var){
        System.out.println("Is an int!");
    }

    public static void varType(String var){
        System.out.println("Is an string!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        String z = "0";
        varType(x);
        varType(y);
        varType(z);
    }
}
```

Resumindo, é feito as chamadas no método estáticos no métodos principal.

O bind dinâmico, é criado uma instancia da classe principal para se usar seus métodos, ex:

```
public class Main{
    public void varType(float var){
        System.out.println("Is an float!");
    }

    public void varType(int var){
        System.out.println("Is an int!");
    }

    public void varType(String var){
        System.out.println("Is an string!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        String z = "0";
        Main m = new Main();
        m.varType(x);
        m.varType(y);
        m.varType(z);
    }
}
```

Referencia: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-dynamic-binding/